# Cloudformation AWS EIP fails with invalid domain vpc

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, eip

I am trying to set up and elastic IP for a network load balancer but every time I create the stack it fails specifying that the domain vpc is an invalid parameter value although the specified vpc physical id exists and it is created before.

Comment: You need to share your code etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you got `Domain: vpc` set in your CloudFormation template?

This should work:

```
ElasticIP:
  Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
  Properties:
    Domain: vpc      # NOT vpc-1234abcd !!
```

If you don't specify `Domain: vpc` you won't be able to attach the *EIP* to resources inside the VPC, e.g. to the load balancer.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. Found it myself afterwards, but it took a few hours.